# Best database structure for building levels and upgrades

Tags: database, sqlite

I'm building a game where the player has to build different types of buildings and can upgrade them. Some buildings may be upgradable to level 30, whereas some others to level 5 only.

I wonder what is the best database layout for that. I am using sqlite3 if that makes any difference, but the questions applies to other engines as well.

I have through of two options for my `buildings` table:

**Option one:** Make a `building_group` column to idenfity which buildings are similar:

```
id (Integer, Auto increment), building_name, building_group, level, points, cost
1, path, 1, 1, 100, 1000
2, road, 1, 2, 200, 2000
3, highway, 1, 3, 300, 3000
4, village, 2, 1, 1000, 10000
5, town, 2, 2, 2000, 20000
6, city, 2, 3, 3000, 30000
```

**Option two:** Have one entry per building and have all level information in the same row. This doesn't seem the best approach to me but I thought I would mention it anyways.

```
id (Integer, Auto increment), building_name_1, points_1, cost_1, building_name_2, points_2, cost_2, building_name_3, points_3, cost_3,...
1, path, 100, 1000,road, 200, 2000, highway, 300, 3000
2, village, 1000, 10000, town, 2000, 20000, city, 3000, 30000
```

I'm sure there are better ways to handle that and I would like to hear your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, the second approach makes very little sense. In order to effectively query or update it, you'll have to construct your column names dynamically, which is a great source for hard to track bugs (not to mention potential vulnerability to SQL injections if you don't do it properly). Moreover, sooner or later, you're going to think of some super-duper special upgrade which has a level higher than the columns you've planned originally, and you'll have to **change the definition of the table** just to accommodate it, which makes no sense at all.

The first design seems like the text-book way of doing things, which will easily allow yo to create complex queries on the buildings and on what a player has or hasn't built. If you ever need to extract some common data to an entire building group you could create another `building_groups` table with that information, and make the `building_group` column in `buildings` a foreign key to its primary key.